# How to test weighted routing policy locally in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-route53

I am building an AWS service with Route53. I have implemented a 50/50 weighted routing policy. There is a single DNS entry e.g. www.example.com. This then points to to servers A and B hosting web sites.

I can navigate to a single server A locally via the domain name. However, I also want to test the routing to Server B.

If I navigate to the domain on my phone and that will route me to server B.

But is there anyway I can get routing to server A and server B on different web pages locally on my PC?

I always get navigated to one of the servers no matter how many web pages I have open locally. I have tried using private modes of web browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer, so the nearest thing I could find was to find a couple of web page test sites such as

These help to test the site from different locations.

https://www.geoscreenshot.com/capture

https://www.locabrowser.com/